# PHP Display JSON

Tags: php, json

I want to do the following in PHP:

Get json data from http://domain.com/api/user/1

This provides:

```
{"name":"Joe","password":"something","email":"something@something.com"}
```

I want to be able to do a simple php echo to display the json data on a webpage

```
<html><?php echo $password ?></html>
<html><?php echo $name ?></html>
<html><?php echo $email ?></html>
```

So basically, creating a php for the "name" / "password" or "email" part of json results

Comment: You have to json_decode the json data and you can get an array result

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<?php

$json = '{"name":"Joe","password":"something","email":"something@something.com"}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'name'}; // Joe
print $obj->{'password'}; // something
print $obj->{'email'}; // something@something.com

?>
```

for more info: https://www.php.net/json_decode